# Android studio cannot open project or taking so long to open

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, exe

Android Projects that were working properly before and saved at drive D:\

And then I format drive C:\ with window 7 32 bit and installed window 7 64 bit.

I created new user instead of using built-in user account and gave admin permission to new user account.

And Install android studio 2.1.3 and used previous working properly SDK.

Creating new android project is fine until it run at virtual device.

***My problem is opening previous projects that was created at android studio and working properly were cannot open happening taking so long at "Buildin  Gradle project info" progress.***

It takes several minutes and it did not open the project.

So Please light upon me to solve this problem and I would like to thank to any comments and possible or near or correct answer that helps my problem.

Here i[image]s a screenshot that I am facing.

Comment: you should remove gradle folder. I had the same problem and i searched about gradle upgrading..., I hope it will help. sorry i don't remember the whole process

Comment: Thank for your comment masoud vali. Should I delete _**.gradle**_ folder or _**gradle**_  folder?

Comment: the gradle folder which there is gradle-wrapper file in it

Comment: Later studio suggest with dialog box to update gradle and updating gradle help to solve this problem I think.